# How to use multiple (dynamic) toggle buttons with same ID on the same page?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a dynamic output from database in my PHP code.
In the code, I have a toggle button which is added to every output element.

The problem is, toggle is properly working only for the first element.
All other elements are just messed up: everything is visible by default and when clicking a button it just scrolls to the first element.

PHP/HTML:

```
<?php
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div class='details'>
              <h4>".$row['image_text']."</h4>
          <input type='submit' id='title_btn' onclick='changeTitle(this)' value='Edit title'>";
    echo "<form action='edittitle.php' method='POST' id='newtitle' autocomplete='off'>
              <input type='text' name='newtitle' value='".$row['image_text']."'/>
              <input type='submit' name='edit' id='title_btn2' value='Save title'>
          </form>";
          </div>";
  }
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('newtitle').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('title_btn2').style.display='none';
}

function changeTitle(eref) {
    var x = document.getElementById('newtitle');
    eref.style.display = 'none';
    var btn;
    if (eref.id == 'title_btn') {
        btn = document.getElementById('title_btn2');
        x.style.display = 'inline-block'
    } else {
        btn = document.getElementById('title_btn');
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
    btn.style.display = 'inline-block';
}
```

I would prefer pure JavaScript solution but if that is not possible, I wouldn't mind using jQuery aswell.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, you can not use the same ID for multiple elements. This should probably be changed to a version using classes instead of IDs, and then access the “right” elements based on their location / relation to each other in the DOM.

Comment: An ID is like a phone number. You can duplicate your SIM card and use the same number in different devices, but only one will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @misorude said ID's have to be unique, so go with a class name instead.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/roe2byfw/)

```
var editToggler = document.querySelectorAll('.title_btn');
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.newtitle');
var savebtn = document.querySelectorAll('.title_btn2');


editToggler.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

    btn.parentElement.querySelector('.newtitle').style.display = 'block';

    btn.style.display = 'none';
  });
});

forms.forEach(function(f) {
  f.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

savebtn.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

    btn.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    btn.parentElement.parentElement
      .querySelector('.title_btn')
      .style.display = 'block';
  });

});
```

Comment: Doesn't really work for multiple forms :/ When clicking one, the rest get messed up. 
Update your JSfiddle to show what happens: https://jsfiddle.net/3n1smaxz/

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Updated :)
Note that i prevent the forms from Redirecting for convenience:

Comment: When I click on the text input field, it hides the form and I can not enter a new title. I bet the solution is simple, but I can not figure it out.. :l

Comment: I've updated it, it doesn't hide the form now and works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery .each():

```
$('.ClassName').each(function(){
    // get current element
    var it = $(this); 
    // hide, show ...
    it.hide();
    it.show();
    // show element -> parent -> children with class .benny
    it.parent().children('.benny').show();
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634975/jquery-each-to-toggle-hidden-elements